# SignalR sqlServer listening

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, signalr

I've noticed there's a SignalR.SqlServer class on github. 
https://github.com/paigecook/SignalR/tree/master/SignalR.SqlServer

Wondering if I can use it to listen for database updates and send them to the client?
If yes, is there any documentation/examples on this feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you can't. This is an implementation of SignalR's IMessageBus on top of SQL Server. It allows you to use SignalR in a webfarm, using Sql server as the backplane to communicate messages to all webnodes.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer.