# VB.net SQL Checking

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've been looking for a couple weeks now on what the best way would be to try and come up with a "push-notification" from SQL to VB.net so i don't have to continuesly run Timers and multiple of them on my forms...

Was curious on what you guys would do / have tried and is working for you?

Comment: Information about a specific use case might help people form an opinion. As it is, without knowing what your goals of the push notification are, it's hard to give a recommendation. For example, notification of what?

Comment: Notification for what?

Comment: Ok say I have a client table and there notes change 1ce a day ... or maybe every 15 minutes ... i want to refresh those notes on a panel " AS THERE BEING CHANGED", but don't want to run a timer every ( say 1 second ) to check for them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered SqlDependency (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx)? Sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

We haven't implemented this in production code. I have a Lazy-ish object that reloads if the value is older than a few minutes old.

Comment: Ill take a look at this , if im looking at the web right you make the dependancy and check it for changes if it does then go out and grab them ... yeah looks like it but want to make sure

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events

would be great to get going on this - thats what i'll do thanks for your advice

Answer (score 2):

SignalR is an emerging technology for polling and long-running transactions (for notification, as you are describing it).
This SO question had some good references:  [How to use SignalR in a webfarm, using Sql server as the backplane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245856/how-to-use-signalr-in-a-webfarm-using-sql-server-as-the-backplane)

Comment: Sorry SignalR ( to me ) is either too advanced or too experimental but thanks for the answer + vote