# Signalr with SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, signalr

I have just came to know about signalr and I am trying to find out that is there any way I can get the notification directly from the sql server. I am not able to find a single example of it on internet. Though, I came to know about *signalr.sqlserver* on githhub but importunately ,again, there is no working example of signalr with sql server on internet.
Can anyone guide me with the tutorial?

Answer (score 5):

As explained here

[SignalR sqlServer listening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810002/signalr-sqlserver-listening)

> This is an implementation of SignalR's IMessageBus on top of SQL
>   Server.

So no, you don't use SignalR from SQL Server itself, it is a web-based tool.

Comment: Thanks.  Perfectly fine question to me, not sure why they closed it.  Thanks for this reply.  I had the exact same question.